# android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu

I try send APDU command with Android NFC:

```
        byte[] selCommand = ApduBuilder.INS(INS.SELECT).P1(NfcActivityA.FileRefControl.GET_BY_DF.code).data("A0000006581010").build();

        Log.d("APDU", "selCommand: "+ fromByteArray(selCommand));

        byte[] result = mNfc.transceive(selCommand);
```

But I get strange behavior:

Way one - I try send command

```
-> log write selCommand: 123(for example) 
-> I get ecxeption `android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.`
```

Way two - I try send command(debug mode)

```
-> log write selCommand: 123(for example) 
-> I stop on `mNfc.transceive(selCommand);` line 
-> I select this line and pres Alt + F8 
-> Evaluate
-> get success response
```

[image]

[image]

Why???

Comment: What program are you using here? What is Alt+F8 supposed to do? Did this work earlier or is it your first attempt?

Comment: @guidot I think we can presume that AndroidStudio is being used.  I can reproduce the issue myself. What he is saying is that if you set a break-point on the line where transceive is called, then use the IDE to evaluate the expression (right click, evaluate expression), the NFC comms work, and you receive an APDU in return, instead of the tag lost error.

Comment: @ip696 where you ever able to overcome this ?